# Protobuf deserialization error. no method found readStringRequireUtf8()

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using protocol buffers as the data exchange format. I using Windows machine to send the message and linux to recieve and deserialize it. It works fine if i desireize in the windows machine . But it fails in linux with this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readStringRequireUtf8()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.nas.protobuf.location.LocationProto$LocationEvent.<init>(LocationProto.java:96)
    at com.nas.protobuf.location.LocationProto$LocationEvent.<init>(LocationProto.java:57)
    at com.nas.protobuf.location.LocationProto$LocationEvent$1.parsePartialFrom(LocationProto.java:832)
    at com.nas.protobuf.location.LocationProto$LocationEvent$1.parsePartialFrom(LocationProto.java:827)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at com.nas.protobuf.location.LocationProto$LocationEvent.parseFrom(LocationProto.java:331)
```

Looks like stange problem.
Protobuf version: **3.1.0**

**Note**: building the both project on windows only. Running one in windows and one in linux and it works fine with protobuf version **2.6.1**

Any suggestions are helpfull

Comment: Make sure in Linux also using Protobuf version: 3.1.0

Comment: both are using common maven library

Comment: This problem is almost certainly because the runtime protobuf jar is a different version from the one you compiled with.